# Using this inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects created with a constructor. This is the constructor definition:

```
function Expander(elem, startingFlipped) {
  this.element = elem;
  this.flipped = startingFlipped;
}
```

(Below, `rawElems` is just a result of `document.getElementsByClassName('foo');`)

Once the DOMContentLoaded event fires, I then do this to find, construct, and push a new object into an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rawElems.length; i++) {
  expanders[i] = new Expander(rawElems[i], false);

  expanders[i].this.element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    console.log("Clicked " + expanders[i].this.element);
  });
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how the syntax for accessing the property for `this`. This currently throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
>       at HTMLSpanElement.

Which is great in some ways, because these ARE `<span>` elements (console logging the object and the array shows it is properly populated).

But since I'm trying this constructor pattern, how do I properly reference the elements inside each object using `this`?

Comment: try `expanders[i].element.....`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I still get the same error, actually (I had tried that as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `expanders[i].this.element` means "look up the property on `expanders` whose name is the value of `i`, then on the result look up a property called `this`, and on the result of *that*, look up a property called `element`.

But your `Expander` object doesn't have a property on it called `this`. If you want to access the `Expander` object at `expanders[i]`, you just use that, you don't add `this.` to it:

```
expanders[i].element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
//          ^--- No this. here
    console.log("Clicked " + this);
    // Here, use `this` -----^
});
```

Within the event handler, `this` will refer to the DOM element that you hooked the event on, so you don't access it via your `Expander` at all.

If you need to access your expander in there, you need to give yourself a reference to it that will still be valid when the event occurs. You can't use `expanders[i]` for that with your current loop, because `i`'s value will have changed before the event happens.

You have lots of options for this part, discussed in [*JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). One of the simplest is to use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `for`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rawElems, function(element, index) {
    var expander = expanders[index] = new Expander(element, false);
    element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        // You can use `element` and `expander` here
        // If you liked, you could *not* have the `expander` variable
        // and use `expanders[index]` here, because unlike the `i` in
        // your `for` loop, the value `index` won't change.
    });
});
```

In an ES2015 (aka "ES6") environment or later, you could use `let` in your `for` loop: `for (let i = 0; i < rawElems.length; ++i)` and then `expanders[i]` *would* work correctly. (`let` is quite different from `var` even though they have similar purposes.)

Or you could use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind `expanders[i]` to the event handler function, then use `this` to refer to the expander, and `this.element` (or `event.currentTarget`) to refer to the element. That has the advantage that you can define the handler *once* and reuse it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rawElems.length; i++) {
  expanders[i] = new Expander(rawElems[i], false);
  expanders[i].element.addaddEventListener("click", handleExpanderClick.bind(expanders[i]));
}
function handleExpanderClick(event) {
    // `this` = the expander
    // `this.element` = the element
    // `event.currentTarget` = the element (also)
}
```

Comment: Oh! Interesting. Could I also simply use a `.map()` method to assign the event handlers to each object.element in the array?

Comment: @armadadrive: Doh! Of course you could: `var expanders = Array.prototype.map.call(rawElems, function(element, index) { /* create, hook up, and return expander here */});` I should have thought of that.

Comment: Hahaha, well I won't hold it against you. Thanks for your time and the well thought-out answer.